# Embedded and Remoting DocuSign process

Tags: c#, asp.net, docusignapi

I am working on a task where there are list of 3 people who needs to sign the document one after the other. The very first persons DocuSign the document through the application i.e. its an embedded DocuSign. While the other 2 does remote DocuSign.

I am able to achieve the embedded signing but could not figure out how to achieve the remote signing. Since the envelopeID is same. Even if I add recipients to the envelope the remote DocuSign email is not triggered.

Can anyone help me on how to go about on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need to see your request body to see how you are adding your recipients, but my guess is that you are setting the latter 2 as embedded also.

To make a recipient an embedded one you need to set the `clientUserId` property for them, in addition to the other expected info (i.e. email, name, etc).  If you do NOT want the recipient to be an embedded one, simply do not set the clientUserId property for them.

For instance, the following (partial) JSON would set the first recipient as an Embedded one and the 2nd and 3rd recipients as remote, meaning will get an email notification to to sign:

```
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "clientUserId": "1000",
        "name": "Sally Doe",
        "email": "test_1@email.com"
      },
      {
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "test_2@email.com"
      },
      {
        "routingOrder": "3",
        "recipientId": "3",
        "name": "Jonny Moe",
        "email": "test_3@email.com"
      }            
    ]
}
```

For more information please see the `Explore` -> `Features` -> `Embedding` page on the DocuSign Developer Center:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign

Comment: thanks a lot Ergin. You were correct I was providing clientUserId for the other 2 users also.